# Как настроить ubuntu на virtualbox, чтобы инет на основной системе шел через виртуалку

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu

Есть машина с `windows7`, инет через роутер раздается по вайфай, через `DHCP`. На машине `ubuntu 10.04` в `virtualbox`, нужно чтобы весь трафик шел через виртуалку. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно почитать [гугль](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ubuntu+as+a+router), хотя бы первые 3 ссылки. Потом может и наша помощь не понадобится.